# Cocos2dx back key function not getting called

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, layer

I implemented the key back click method for the layer in cocos2dx 2.2.3,but it doesn't get called when i press back....

I thought this new version was supposed to fix things... How should I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the target for higher version device.